# Make content sticky on scroll to a point in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed, sticky

I have a `div` that's set to `position: relative`. It becomes `fixed` when the top of the window reaches it. The div lives in a container (blue in the example below) and I would like to set it back to `relative` when it reaches the bottom of its parent container (blue).

This is my code simplified and my [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/julienfrog/p87jmj61/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="green"></div>

<div class="blue">
  <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
</div>

<div class="red"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 500px;
}

.sticky {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 800px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

**And the jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
      $('.sticky').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
      $('.sticky').css('position', 'relative');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add following condition to your `if` statement:

```
$(".blue").height() + $(".blue").offset().top > windowTop
```

Your code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var stickyTop = $('.sticky').offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (stickyTop < windowTop && $(".blue").height() + $(".blue").offset().top - $(".sticky").height() > windowTop) {
      $('.sticky').css('position', 'fixed');
    } else {
      $('.sticky').css('position', 'relative');
    }
  });
});
```

See [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p87jmj61/3/).

Answer (score 0):

you can make it with [jquery.sticky.js](http://stickyjs.com/) plugin

add an id to the element you want to stick

```
$('#sticky').sticky();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
       var navpos1 = $('.header').offset().top(); 
           if (navpos1) {
              $('body').addClass('fixedHd');
            } else {
                 $('body').removeClass('fixedHd');
                 }
  });
```